# SQL report: count total rows per user and count successful transactions per user

Tags: sql, firebird

We are using a Firebird 2.1 database and trying to run a query for a report that counts total transactions and transactions of a certain status. Each transaction has a status that is either successful (1) or unsuccessful (0). There was also a denied status (2) but that's covered in the comments. I'll use ambiguous data.

```
USER_ID, Fruit, Eaten
----------------------
1, Apple, 0
1, Banana, 1
1, Kiwi, 1
2, Apple, 1
2, Banana, 1
3, Apple, 0
```

What we would like to do is run a report that shows USER_ID, TOTAL_FRUIT, and EATEN_FRUIT. Where TOTAL_FRUIT counts the total number of transactions and EATEN_FRUIT counts the total of successful transactions based on 0 or 1

```
USER_ID, TOTAL_FRUIT, EATEN_FRUIT 
---------------------------------
1, 3, 2
2, 2, 2
3, 1, 0
```

Our "best" attempt at an SQL statement for this was:

```
WITH alias1 AS 
        (SELECT USER_ID, count(Fruit) as TOTAL_FRUIT FROM myTable GROUP BY USER_ID),
     alias2 AS
        (SELECT USER_ID, count(Fruit) as EATEN_FRUIT FROM myTable WHERE Eaten=1 GROUP BY USER_ID)
SELECT alias2.USER_ID, TOTAL_FRUIT, EATEN_FRUIT
FROM alias1, alias2
```

However, both datasets alone work fine but, when processed together, the first dataset is only the first row over and over again.

Comment: Have you used `GROUP BY` before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use count(*), sum() and group by

```
select user_id, count(*), sum(eaten)
from my_table 
group by user_id
```

you can eventually also manage for null value

```
select user_id, count(*), sum(coalesce(eaten,0))
from my_table 
group by user_id
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! So, we just found out that we have a "EATEN" status of 2 which is declined. We are using: select user_id, count(*), sum(CASE WHEN eaten = 1 THEN 1 END)
from my_table 
group by user_id

Comment: oh sorry. right, so we found out there is a 0 case for not processed, 1 case for processed, and a 2 for denied. So, we have to sum all the processed cases but exclude 2 because it was denied. My case statement didn't work any ways. Truly sorry for the ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertBroden Instead of `CASE` you can use `NULLIF` - like so: `SUM(NULLIF(eaten,2))`

Comment: Firebird has `NULLIF`: http://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-nullif.html  -- I think you may have misread my comment

Comment: This was very helpful thanks! I'm not sure that I got the right results but I am going to chat with my colleague tomorrow to get this working. I have to ask him if there is some other reason the results are wrong. Thank you so much!